# Motion graphics animations in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-animation, opengl-es-2.0, objectanimator

I was wondering what will be the best solution or method to implement motion graphics animations in an android application .

Check out this website.

https://uxplanet.org/bringing-mobile-apps-to-life-through-motion-9472d259b58e

I want to implement same type of animations.

How can I do that?
What is the best industry standard to do this?

Should I be using After Effects animations and render them into android application or can I achieve this using Open GLES ? Which will be the fast and efficient way ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you at least read: https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/index.html and https://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Design is no doubt an integral part of any app. Hence, design must also be taken in consideration along with the functionalities of the app. Motion Graphics in Android can be implemented in many ways. Android itself provides a rich set of powerful APIs to implement animations to various UI elements. For animations, Android has the '**PropertyAnimation**', '**ViewAnimation**' and the '**DrawableAnimation**'. The Property Animation is a powerful system which can be used to achieve complex animations for both View and nonView objects. The view and drawable animations are a bit simpler systems to achieve simpler animations.

For drawing graphics in Android, you can use the Android Canvas or the OpenGL ES. OpenGL is an extremely powerful tool for manipulating and displaying high-end animated 3D graphics and can use hardware accelerated GPU. Please look into the Android docs for exact codes for implementation.

Now considering After Effects animations, they are really neat and perfectly fit the design aspects of the app. However the animations rendered by After Effects tend to be large in size and end up making the final app big in size. Personally, I have used AE rendered animations for my splashscreen and only a few other animations. Finally, it depends on your coding abilities since implementing complex animations using Android systems would be hard, whereas AE animations would make the app size large.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: what about Lottie? Its an open source tool for rendering AE animations

Comment: I wasn't familiar with Lottie but a quick search shows that Lottie is a good source. Personally I created my own AE animations. Using Lottie for animations is a good idea.